# URL is being changed unexpectedly when using custom redirect with constants

Tags: php, plesk

My site uses a PLESK server. I have recently changed the document root from `httpdocs` to `httpdocs/public`. This is to add additional security to privately used files.

However, I have found that it isn't redirecting correctly. For example. I have a index.php that is in the public directory that for now automatically redirects to the admin directory. Let me walk you through how I determine certain constants and then the two functions that I use to redirect.

There are are few contstants as defined below:

```
<?php
// Assign file paths to PHP constants
// __FILE__ returns the current path to this file
// dirname() returns the path to the parent directory
define("PRIVATE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
define("PROJECT_PATH", dirname(PRIVATE_PATH));
define("PUBLIC_PATH", PROJECT_PATH . '/public');
define("SHARED_PATH", PRIVATE_PATH . '/shared');
define("ARRAY_PATH", PRIVATE_PATH . '/arrays');

// Assign the root URL to a PHP constant
// * Do not need to include the domain
// * Use same document root as webserver
// * Can dynamically find everything in URL up to "/public"
$public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/public') + 7;
$doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $public_end);
define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);
```

Then here are the two functions in my functions.php that is included in the initialize.php (the above snippet is from initialize.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * @param string $script_path
 * @return string
 */
function url_for(string $script_path): string
{
    // add the leading '/' if not present
    if ($script_path[0] != '/') {
        $script_path = "/" . $script_path;
    }
    return WWW_ROOT . $script_path;
}

/**
 *
 * @param string $loc
 */
function redirect_to(string $loc): void
{
    header("Location: " . $loc);
    exit;
}
```

Below is that index.php mentioned beforehand

```
<?php
require_once('../private/initialize.php');
header('Location: ' . url_for('admin'));
```

Notice that in this instance I am not using the redirect_to() function. This is the output url I am getting:

> https://mydomainname.com/index./admin

This is invalid and throws a 404 http error. So decided to see what would happen if I went to what I had expected the URL to be which was

> https://mydomainname.com/admin

The page is found BUT the css and js files for my project are not being found. Interestingly, I see evidence that they are included though because the css and js are dynamically loaded from the private directory through the SHARED_PATH constant. So why am I seeing this index. and how would I stop it is my basic question.